# IIR Design with Neural Networks

Tags: c++, filter, neural-network

i'm trying to apply this paper using C++:

[Design of Digital Recursive Filter Using Artificial Neural Network](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/IMECS2012/IMECS2012_pp35-38.pdf)

In this paper the weights are the coefficients and they start with weight a(0) = 1 and all other weights are zero.

Does someone would be nice enough to provide detailed pseudo-code for that algorithm because I don't get it at all, and it seems quite powerful and interesting.

1. I don't know what is the input vector x(m)
2. I don't get how to compute ∆w
3. or the desired output dm

Comment: You need to show some semblance of effort on your part, instead of just posting the paper. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: i made the effort but there are some parts missing that are maybe obvious to some people but not to me